# Return all numbers with more then 2 decimal digits in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have data similar to this in my database:

```
+----+----------------+
| id | summ (varchar) |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | 30.23          |
|  2 | 10.235         |
|  3 | 20.2300        |
|  4 | 100.005        |
|  5 | 5.031          |
|  6 | 0.0010002      |
+----+----------------+
```

How can I receive all data, in MySQL query that has more then 2 decimal digits ( zeros also count )?

At start I had to get only the ones, that have 3 digits and end with 5, so I used this command `substring( summs * 100, -2 ) = '.5'`, but I have no idea how to get the various numbers.

Comment: You can subtract an appropriately 'floored' value. Anything with a non-zero result will be what you're after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this :-

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE LENGTH(SUBSTR(`summ `,INSTR(`summ `,"."))) >3
```

Comment: Thank you. I just changed `>2` to `>3` and it all worked, since >2 also includes the **`.`** in it's query and returns 2+, not 3+.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this also:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE columnName <> ROUND (columnName, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the SQL query to exclude "20.23" but include "20.2300", yes?

Given that theses are strings, and not floating point numbers, you could use string functions in your query, specifically a combination of [INSTR()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm#function_instr) and LENGTH().  Use the former to locate the decimal point (period) and then compare that to the length of the string (minus 2).

Answer (score 0):

**I guess the solution from @Rahul Tripathi is most probably the best.**

But I tried something in a different context and found another *possible* solution based on the answers from this question: [Store only numbers after Comma mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043639/store-only-numbers-after-comma-mysql)

This solution is rather "heavily restricted" in which cases it would correctly work because of how MySQL works with and stores floating point values etc. etc.

Assuming that `summ` is a number (if a string, then casting is required or just use the solution from @Rahul Tripathi). And `summ` would be better to be a *decimal* number instead of *float* because of precision and storage reasons.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE (LENGTH(TRIM(TRAILING "0" from MOD(`summ`, 1))) - 2) > 2;
```

To test it:

```sql
set @fraction = 100.005;
set @modulo = mod(@fraction, 1);
set @modulo = trim(trailing "0" from @modulo);
set @decimals = length(@modulo) - 2;

select @fraction, @modulo, @decimals;
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| @fraction | @modulo | @decimals |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
|   100.005 |   0.005 |         3 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note: casting with `CAST("12.345" as DECIMAL(10,5))` requires prior knowledge about the number of digits than can appear. If you are computing the values in the database or cast them from a string with `"12.345" + 0`, it would somewhat work but because of how binary floating point numbers are stored, you would get something like: `"12.345" + 0` → `12.34500000000000064` which would not be the anwser you may have wanted. You could then try to round again to remove digits after a certain possition and so on ...