# Store only numbers after Comma mysql

Tags: mysql

How to save only the numbers after the comma with mysql functions?

eg : `16.03` ----> `03`

Comment: **What possible purpose does it serve to put your entire question in boldface?**

Comment: `$numbersAfterComma = fmod(16.03, 1);`

Comment: After the comma? Or after the decimal point?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to *store* only the decimal part of a number (at `INSERT` time)? Or are you looking for a way to *extract* only the decimal part of a number (at `SELECT` time)?

Comment: i want extract only decimal part of number at SELECT

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want the fractional part of the number.  In MySQL, you can do this with `mod()`:

```
select mod(14.03, 1)
```

Yields "0.03".

EDIT:

Juhana makes a very good point.  MySQL freely converts between numbers and strings, so you can use `substr()` on this:

```
select substr(14.03, locate('.', 14.03)+1)
```

If you want the digits after a comma, replace `'.'` with `','`.

Comment: The question asks for `03`, not `0.03`.

Comment: @Juhana . . . Thank you for pointing out what should have been obvious.

Comment: I don't think this works if the value is an integer since MySQL will not append `.0` while converting it to string (i.e.: the value `5.0` is converted to the string `"5"`).

Answer (score 0):

If your values come from a table, you will have to be prepared to deal with the fact that some value could be integers (i.e.: having no decimal separator while converted to a string):

```
SELECT IF(LOCATE('.', value), SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,'.', -1), "0") FROM tbl;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/062c8/11

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
14.03 % 1

--> 0.03
```

Also works for negative numbers:

```
-14.03 % 1

--> -0.03
```

If you are after exactly the two digits after the decimal point (and you are dealing with positive numbers only) you can do the following:

```
substring(format( num %1,2),3,2)  -- num being the column (integer of float, double ...)
--> 03  -- for num=14.03
--> 00  -- for num=14
--> 05  -- for num=14.046739
```

Of course, if you want all digits, you could leave out the `format()`

```
substring(num %1,3,2)
--> 03      -- for num=14.03
-->         -- for num=14
--> 046739  -- for num=14.046739
```

but that makes the integer case quite ugly.